# Relation between $\mathcal R$ , $\mathcal L$ , $\mathcal H$ and $\mathcal D$ class on a Semigroup $S$

Tags: semigroups

I am studying Semigroup Theory from a book by **John M. Howie**. I have questions about **THE STRUCTURE OF $\mathcal D -$ CLASSES** on page 49:

If D is an arbitrary $\mathcal D - $ class in a Semigroup $S$ and if $a, b \in D$ are such that $a \mathcal R b$ , then by the definition of $\mathcal R$ there exist $s , s' \in S^1 $ such that

$$ as = b , \ \  \ \ bs' = a\ .$$

The right translation map $\rho_s : S \rightarrow S$ such that $(x)\rho_s = xs$ thus maps $a$ to $b$ and maps $\mathcal L_a$ into $\mathcal L_b$.

Similarly $\rho_{s'}$ maps $\mathcal L_b$ into $\mathcal L_a$, the composition  $\rho_s \rho_{s'}$ is the identity map on $\mathcal L_a$ and  $\rho_{s'} \rho_{s}$ is the identity map on $\mathcal L_b$

We deduce that $\rho_s|\mathcal L_a$ and $\rho_{s'}|\mathcal L_b$ are mutually inverse bijections from $\mathcal L_a$ onto $\mathcal L_b$ and $\mathcal L_b$ onto $\mathcal L_a$.

We can say even more about these maps; if $x \in \mathcal L_a$, then the element $ y = x\rho_s$ of $\mathcal L_b$ has the property that

$$ y = xs , \ \ \ \ x = ys'\ .$$

Thus $y \mathcal R x $, and so the map $\rho_s$ is $\mathcal R$ - class preserving.

> > Firstly, what does $\mathcal R - $ class preserving mean?

Secondly,

> > Show that $\rho_s$ maps each $\mathcal H$ class in $\mathcal L_a$ in a one-one manner onto the corresponding ($\mathcal R$ - equivalent ) $\mathcal H$ classes in $\mathcal L_b$.

For the second part:

Define $K_a = \{ \mathcal H_x : \mathcal H_x \subseteq \mathcal L_a \}$

and $K_b = \{ \mathcal H_y : \mathcal H_y \subseteq \mathcal L_b \}$.

I think we need to show that for any $\mathcal H_x \in K_a$, we have that $\rho_s(\mathcal H_x) \in K_b$

How to show that $\rho_s(\mathcal H_x)  = \{ ys : y \in  \mathcal H_x \}$ is in $K_b$.

I would be thankful if someone could help me.

Comment: For the first one, it means that if you pick an element in an $\mathcal{R}$-class and apply the function, you get an element in the same $\mathcal{R}$-class you started with.

Comment: So you need to show that if $x$ and $y$ are both left equivalent to $a$ and are right equivalent to each other, then $xs$ and $ys$ are left equivalent to $b$ and still right equivalent to each other.

Comment: For the first, I think, it should say that $\rho_s$ is $\mathcal R$ oreserving on $\mathcal L$ , because $\rho_s$ is preserving every element of $\mathcal L_a$.

Comment: @ Sardobi ; Thanks for editing